# Using ajax to display page as floating div

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I need to make the following button on my page:

Clicking on the button results in a div that floats above the page and loads in another internal page.

This should be done with Ajax, am I right? I have absolutely zero knowledge of ajax so I don't have a clue how to proceed.

This is what I have right now:

```
<div id="clickmebutton" onclick="javascript:FloatingPage();">Click me</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function FloatingPage() {
   new Ajax.Request('/floatingpage.php' {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('subcontent').innerHTML = response.responseText;

        } 
   });
}
</script>
```

and as css

```
#layer subcontent {background-color: aqua; width:100px; height: 100px; margin:8px; display: none;}
```

**Edit:** What I'm trying to make is an image picker within my form. The div will show the images on the server and listed in the database as an < option >. I can then select the image I want to use in the form, get the id and sent the id in my form.

**Solution** Using the dialog() function from the jquery ui I got what I wanted.

Comment: The ajax thing only makes sense if the internal page contents come dynamically from a server . Did what you try work ? In theory it should , if floatingpage.php actually returns the right html.

Comment: You don't need AJAX, depending on what you are trying to do. Is this an offline page? Do you have a server running? And finally what exactly is your problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: This is indeed the case. The internal page lists photo's that can be selected and will then return an id to the page it's coming from.

@stackErr
I don't get any error, the script doesn't work.

Comment: @Nijn what if you input this in your browser `yourwebsite.com/floatingpage.php`? Do you get your page displayed?
Also can you explain what happens when you click the button?

Comment: This returns the page as it should. When I click the button, nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use fancybox to display webpages and media on my website. It uses JQuery and it is simple to implement. You can find more info and instructions here http://fancybox.net/

You can display everything from internal webpages through to Youtube videos and Google maps.

I would recommend using JQuery to implement a floating div instead of Ajax as it's easy to put together and requires no previous expertise.

Comment: I see the fancybox.net as a last result. It should be easy to make a floating div right? Using only JQuery is also an option for me. How should I approach this?

Comment: JQuery uses plugins, there are loads of different ones available. I would have a look here and see if you can find one appropriate to your requirements. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: The problem with dialog is that when I have a select that is inside the dialog, it will not get posted when I submit my form.

Comment: Got it! By tweaking the modal form from dialog() I got it to work. Thanks for the tip, great help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted pal.